# Can't run npm in visual stuido terminal

Tags: reactjs, npm, visual-studio-code, terminal

I am install react & angular on the system. but when I write `npm start` in visual studio code. it shows an error.

if anyone knows how to fix this problem please tell me. it's very helpful for me. I am trying to fix this error last 4 hours

```html
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Pooja Patel\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-07T14_31_21_583Z-debug.log      
PS C:\Users\Pooja Patel\Desktop\evalue webpage> npm run
Lifecycle scripts included in ionicstore@1.0.0:
  test
    echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1

PS C:\Users\Pooja Patel\Desktop\evalue webpage> npm start
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
PS C:\Users\Pooja Patel\Desktop\evalue webpage> npm start
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages       
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Pooja Patel\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-07T15_54_08_904Z-debug.log      
PS C:\Users\Pooja Patel\Desktop\evalue webpage>
```

Comment: Please show `package.json` file

Comment: Do you have a `package.json` in current directory ? and does it have `start` script in it ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your `package.json` file doesnt have scripts, so when you run `npm run start`, npm cant find the `start` script in it.
So, open and edit your `package.json` file and write a script in order to run it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In my case, I had to go to the folder itself in which the project is located. As I understand it, in the C:\Users\Pooja Patel\Desktop\evalue webpage>   folder you still have a folder in which the project is located. Just go into it and even then write **npm start**.